# I am designing dictionary which words and meaning are store in an arrays, its work but am getting warning message

Tags: flutter, dart

I am designing a dictionary, which words and meanings are store in an arrays, its works, but, am getting  warning message, Here is the message.
which is its take a longer time before its load and run no android emulator. its delay more than 40 minutes before loading on android emulator

here is the warning message

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/Choreographer( 4018): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 4018): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 4018): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 4018): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 4018): Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 4018): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Consider using SQLite to create a database on your device which you can then query. It should be much more efficient.

Comment: Do you have some loop that’s running an insane amount of times on your device?

Comment: @Mr. Matthew Trent, I only have a list view with a length not less than 7000